# RedirectToAction is not redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, action

Shouldn't this work?

[image]

If I had a break point on the last `}` it stops there but it never gets to the `Contact` Action, and the page after being posted it's just a blank page with no source code

**what am I missing**?

Thank you.

Comment: the code removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Contact(ContactModel model) should not be "void", instead it should be

```
public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel model)
{
    //.... some code

    return RedirectToAction("Contact");
}
```

Comment: ahhh, so, it does not return to an actions, but will return what's in that action. Got it, thanks!